# Who is taking care of the Blog?

Tags: discussion, blog, moderation

Supposedly someone is monitoring the [blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/), but I submitted a post for review a few days ago and have heard nadda. Last time I submitted a post (the [Harry Potter Movie Marathon](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/harry-potter-movie-marathon-highlights/)) I ended up pestering the Moderators until one of them approved it.

If this position is open, I'd be willing to be the blog master, as long as it comes with a good parking spot. I don't want to be stuck parking next to the Forbidden Forest or something.

Comment: [Tony](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) hasn't formally resigned, but he hasn't been active for several months. Tony, unless you pipe up soon, I think we'll be formally nominating your replacement. Jack, your candidacy is noted, let's wait a few days to see if there are other candidates.

Comment: In the meantime, do pester a moderator if you want a post published (ping us in chat).

Comment: Plum spot - right IN THE MIDDLE of Forbidden Forest! No need to walk "from near" it! And personal parking guard in the form of man eating spiders!

Comment: Make sure to bring along some extra men to feed to the spiders, so they don't eat you.

Comment: @Xantec: Or bring the [Light of Eärendil](http://xkcd.com/1087/).

Answer (score 4):

Jack, you're in charge now.  I upped you to an 'Editor' on the blog, which looks like it gives you all the power to manage your own and others' posts.

Now you need to get to the job of encouraging others to write more stuff for the blog!