# Ways that you can contribute to the blog.

Tags: discussion, blog

Now that I've been kinda sortof [put in charge](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2116/1148) of the [blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1) I'd like to continue to see contributions.

**Ways you can contribute**

- Review a science fiction or fantasy work (new or otherwise). This could be tv, movies, comics, books, and merchandise (box sets, or toys).
- Write about a recent event, such as if you attended a convention or other specialized function.
- Submit a short story+, or a preview chapter from a scifi/fantasy work you have published or are working on. If your submission is lengthy it might be good to break it out and serialize it over a period of time.

**One idea on how a lot of people can contribute a little bit**

I had an idea for a group contributed short story. Basically, one would start the story (maybe a 1-2 page chapter) then someone else would continue the story, then a third person would continue off that. The evolution of the story could make it fun for people to participate, and it is an opportunity to build something together as part of the scifi.se community.

**How to help even if you won't be able to personally contribute**

And hey, if you have other ideas, even if you don't have time to work on them, mention them here, maybe someone else will be able to take your idea and make something from it.

*+I've been told that fan fictions based on existing work (such as Star Trek) may pose a legal issue for the StackExchange Network. Please refrain from submitting stories set in a franchise which are not available for license-free use or may be copyright restricted.*

Comment: I can do a review of Charles Stross's new novel Rule 34, but someone needs to hook me up with a posting account.

Comment: Did you take charge in a bloody coup?  Because they're the best kinds of coup.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the time to write this particular entry, but it would be a good idea to list and describe all new Science Fiction and Fantasy TV show that are starting soon. It could also list the shows that will goes for a new season.

The description should include a brief description, the premiere dates and a link to the official site (or others) for further information. Since we are a international site, We should put emphasis on highly anticipated series or new show season, not on air dates and broadcasting network.

The good thing is that kind of blog entry could be periodic.

Comment: I'll take this one.  I'll focus on the upcoming Fall US TV schedule.  In a few months I can do a Spring US TV schedule one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Would anyone like to do an episode-by-episode review of the latest Doctor Who episodes?  In the first half of the current season, we had a lot of traffic to the site (not necessarily the greatest questions or answers, but certainly many people coming along), and it seems likely that there could be a similar spike with the final half.

I'm thinking that the reviews could contain spoilers - a short but detailed analysis of the episode, with the new information that the episode adds to the overall season arc as well as opinion about the quality of the episode.

We're a couple of episodes in, so we could quickly push out some for those two, or we could just start at #3.

Comment: *(5 years later)* I'd be up for this. Still need to understand how this whole blog thing works, but ...

Answer (score 2):

I've reccently watched all of Supernatural, I would love to do a multi-part combined blog with other users about the seasons, perhaps one decent post per season? What do other fans of supernatural think?

On a side note, if a post it here are there any restrictions on where else to post the blogs?

Comment: The original blog post http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/703/how-do-i-contribute-to-the-blog has a statement about all submissions being under the Attribution, Share-alike Creative Commons license. I am not aware of any restriction if you have another site which you want to duplicate the same blog post. One thing I've periodically started doing is just giving a sumamry of links for scifi.se on my regular website (http://atwitsendcomics.com/blogs/view/144/Scifi.StackExchange)