# How to get permission to write in SFF.SE blog?

Tags: support, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways that you can contribute to the blog.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2156/ways-that-you-can-contribute-to-the-blog)

I have found on this question: [What is written on Darth Vader's Chest control panel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22676/what-is-written-on-darth-vaders-chest-control-panel) that a member of this site has wrote a blog post for this site. Who has such permissions? And, how to get that?

Comment: See [How do I contribute to the blog?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/703) for the technical details, in particular how to create an account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a link at the top of the blog called "contribute"

http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/contribute/